# Laravel cant able to use Form Request validation in Forgot password controller

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5.5

In the ForgotPasswordController controller having the below method to validate,

```
protected function validateEmail(Request $request)
    {  
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email|exists:users'
        ]);
    }
```

The above is working fine, but i want to do validate with this with *Form Request* validation, so here is the below code

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
use App\Http\Requests\AdminForgotPasswordEmailValidation;
class ForgotPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset emails and
    | includes a trait which assists in sending these notifications from
    | your application to your users. Feel free to explore this trait.
    |
    */

    use SendsPasswordResetEmails;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:admin');
    }

    /**
     * Display the form to request a password reset link.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showLinkRequestForm()
    {
        return view('admin.passwords.email');
    }

    public function broker()
    {
        return Password::broker('admins');
    }

    protected function validateEmail(AdminForgotPasswordEmailValidation $request)
    {

        //nothing here

    }

}
```

Having a strange error,

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ForgotPasswordController::validateEmail() must be an instance of App\Http\Requests\AdminForgotPasswordEmailValidation, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given, called in /home/**/public_html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/SendsPasswordResetEmails.php on line 28
```

This Form Request validations are working fine in other forms

Comment: can you update your question with full controller and AdminForgotPasswordEmailValidation code??

Comment: `working fine in other forms` here `forms` means `controllers` ro `methods` ? share related controller code?

Comment: @Sohel0415, updated the full code

Comment: @user2486 i mean in the normal crud operations done in another controllers the form request is working

Comment: @arunkumar : check after including `use App\Http\Requests\AdminForgotPasswordEmailValidation;` ?

Comment: actually i included this `use...` here updated the code wrongly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't the method the router is dispatching to, therefor the dependency injection isn't happening on that method. `sendResetLinkEmail` is what the route is pointing to, which calls `validateEmail($request)`.

`php artisan route:list`

```
POST      | password/email                 | password.email     | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail
```

Override `sendResetLinkEmail` on `ForgotPasswordController` to not call `$this->validateEmail($request)` and make the signature have a typehint for your request class.

```
public function sendResetLinkEmail(AdminForgotPasswordEmailValidation $request)
```

That would resolve your Form Request which would cause it to validate.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line before your class

```
use App\Http\Requests\AdminForgotPasswordEmailValidation;
```